# event.point not resizing with paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

This will drag my rectangle path. It works perfectly if the window hasn't resized.

```
function onMouseDrag(event) {
  MyRectanglePath.position = event.point;
}
```

This will resize my game to be a square at either 100% width or 100% length of the browser window.

```
    function OnResizeCalled() {
            var gameWidth = window.innerWidth;
            var gameHeight = window.innerHeight;
            var scaleToFitX = gameWidth / 640;
            var scaleToFitY = gameHeight / 640;

            var currentScreenRatio = gameWidth / gameHeight;
            var optimalRatio = Math.min(scaleToFitX, scaleToFitY);
            canvas.style.width = 640 * optimalRatio + "px";
            canvas.style.height = 640 * optimalRatio + "px";
    }

// Resize
window.addEventListener("resize", OnResizeCalled, false);
OnResizeCalled();
```

The smaller my browser window gets, the farther the rectangle is from my mouse when I drag it. How do I make event.point scale with the rest of the canvas?

Answer (score 4):

Paper.js is not designed to support manual resizing of the canvas, since that will blow up the pixels and cause all kind of internal issues. It will also interfere with HiDPI handling on Retina screens.

but you can resize the canvas using:

`paper.view.viewSize = [width, height];`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for your support, Mr. Jürg Lehni! Does this mean I should erase the line 'canvas.style.width = ...' and 'canvas.style.height = ...'? I'd like to make a box that's the full width or height of the screen for a chess app.

Comment: See here for instructions for how to make a Paper.js canvas automatically resize itself to the full window size:
http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#canvas-configuration

Comment: Awesome. I'll check it out. I submitted a pull request to your paperjs, by the way. Great work making paperjs!

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks! And would you mind upvoting / accepting my answer? Not sure how it works but I think that's what Stackoverflow is all about. New around here still...

Comment: I'll upvote your answer, but I'm still having trouble solving this. Maybe I can add more to the documentation about this when I figure it out. There's no examples in the reference, which would be extremely helpful (I'm an UX/Human-Computer Interaction guy). How would paper.view.viewSize = [?, ?] be used to stretch it to fullscreen? I really appreciate your time and effort helping me. You're the defacto expert on this.

Comment: Well the easiest way is to mark your canvas as resizing by add the "resize" attribute to it. Look at the examples that come with the library, they all do this and scale along with the browser without any added code. Internally they use #viewSize and a resize handler to do so: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/master/src/ui/View.js#L49

Answer (score 0):

Umm as Mr. Jürg Lehni stated before, Paper.js is not designed to support manual resizing of the canvas. when paper.view.setViewSize() extends/ shrink the canvas to that size.

If you want to scale the things inside the canvas (e.g. path), you had to apply transformation to every item (with right Matrix) using .transform();